# Too sub-table or not to sub-table? that is the questi0n

Tags: database-design

I would like to know what the rule of thumb is regarding sub tables in a relational DB?

For example.

In the picture below i have replaced a few fields with sub-tables, because there can me multiple, but limited, instances of each

Is this overkill or the preferred way of DB design?

**Second normal form (2NF) further addresses the concept of removing duplicative data:**

1. Meet all the requirements of the first normal form.
2. Remove subsets of data that apply to multiple rows of a table and place them in separate tables.
3. Create relationships between these new tables and their predecessors through the use of foreign keys.

[image]

P.S. I know a uuid is not a INT and will change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there will be more than one instance of the same data in the same table, there should be a relationship formed. Duplicate data is difficult to manage and you leave a lot of room for bugs.

As long as you don't have 2 references of the same data in one table, you're safe.

> Database normalization is the process of organizing the fields and tables of a relational database to minimize redundancy.

See: [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

You're on the right track.